# Error using GeoServer with IIS (XMLHttpRequest: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin')

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, geoserver, arr

I'm trying to use ARR to get layers from GeoServer to load on a web map hosted on IIS because I keep getting the `"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."` error in my console.

I tried adding an ARR rule to the IIS website, but it doesn't change anything. I think that I might not understand well of this is supposed to work.

The rule is:

```
Requested URL: Matches the pattern
Pattern: geoserver.+
Rewrite URL: http://localhost:8080/{R:0}
```

Anyone can point what I'm doing wrong ?

**Edit:** 
I followed this procedure: https://forums.iis.net/t/1189344.aspx but it doesn't work, I'm getting a `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error`. My IIS server adress is `http://localhost:1234/` and geoserver is `http://localhost:8080`. I wrote the localhost:1234 url in the GeoServer global setting, but I couldn't change the parameter in the web.xml as it doesn't seem to exist in my geoserver version (2.8) ...

Comment: does https://forums.iis.net/t/1189344.aspx help?

Comment: I followed the step by step procedure and I'm now getting a `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error. My IIS server adress is `http://localhost:1234/` and geoserver is `http://localhost:8080`. I wrote the localhost:1234 url in the GeoServer global setting, but I couldn't change the parameter in the web.xml as it doesn't seem to exist in my geoserver version (2.8)

Comment: "I tried adding an ARR rule to the IIS website" — You have to add the headers to GeoServer's response. Your site can't give itself permission to read data from third party sites using your visitors' browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Quentin, but can you help me achieve that ? I'm kind of lost with all that...